# Import data from Excel into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, delphi

I need to import data from Excel into a SQL Server database.  I use ADO to read the excel files.

Sometimes it happens that a row is empty in Excel, which will create an empty row import failure on the SQL Server side.

Any good idea to remove these empty rows or detect during import?

I'm looking for a rather effective code style solution, i show my current solution with the field loop here

```
function EmptyRow(aQuery: TADOQuery): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
  fname: string;
  temp_line: string;
begin

  temp_line := '';
  for i := 0 to aQuery.Fields.Count - 1 do
  begin
    fname := aQuery.Fields[i].FieldName;
    temp_line := temp_line + aQuery.FieldByName(fname).asString;
  end;
  if (temp_line <> '') then
    result := false
  else
    result := true;
end;
```

Comment: If you want help with this, add the code you're using to your q.  You can't reasonably expect readers to guess what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could exit the first thime you find a non empty string

```
function EmptyRow(aQuery: TADOQuery): Boolean;
var
  Field: TField;
begin
  for Field in aQuery.Fields do
    if Field.AsString <> '' then
      exit(false);

  exit(True);
end;
```

And if you have an older Delphi you could implement it like tihs:

```
function EmptyRow(aQuery: TADOQuery): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 0 to aQuery.Fields.Count - 1 do
    if aQuery.Fields[I].AsString <> '' then
      exit;

  Result := True;
end;
```